# LIMIT 1 com LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom para começar irei postar o SQL que montei aqui:

```
    SELECT
    a.*,
    b.name AS currentClubName,
    c.name AS transferorClubName,
    d.name AS contactName,
    d.phone AS contactPhone,
    d.phoneApp AS contactPhoneApp,
    d.email AS contactEmail,
    d.note AS contactNote,
    e.endDate
FROM
    athlete a
        LEFT JOIN clubs b ON a.currentClubCode = b.code
        LEFT JOIN clubs c ON a.transferorClubCode = c.code
        LEFT JOIN contacts d ON a.contactCode = d.code
        LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON e.athleteCode = a.code
ORDER BY
    a.name;
```

Tendo em mente que a tabela `athlete` tem apenas um `a.currentClubCode`,`a.transferorClubCode` e um `a.contactCode`, a resposta não vai sofrer duplicidade.

Porém no caso da tabela `negotiation` são registrado várias negociações para um atleta e eu preciso recuperar apenas a `e.endDate` da maior data, ou seja apenas um resultado.

Da forma atual estou tendo uma duplicidade, se um jogador tiver 3 registro na tabela `negotiation` ele é listado 3 vezes no *select*.

Como resolver isso? Eu tentei usar o `LEFT JOIN` pois pode não haver registro de negociação e portanto campo `e.endDate` deve estar nulo.

Obs: estou usando a versão 8 do *mysql*.

Segue a estrutura da tabela `negotiation`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `negotiation` (
  `code` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `athleteCode` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `endDate` date NOT NULL,
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `link` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`),
  FOREIGN KEY (athleteCode) REFERENCES athlete(code) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

__________ edit _____________

Consegui o resultado que eu queria dessa forma, porém não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer isso:

```
    SELECT
    a.*,
    b.name AS currentClubName,
    c.name AS transferorClubName,
    d.name AS contactName,
    d.phone AS contactPhone,
    d.phoneApp AS contactPhoneApp,
    d.email AS contactEmail,
    d.note AS contactNote,
   (SELECT endDate FROM negotiation WHERE athleteCode = a.code ORDER BY endDate DESC LIMIT 1) AS endDate
FROM
    athlete a
        LEFT JOIN clubs b ON a.currentClubCode = b.code
        LEFT JOIN clubs c ON a.transferorClubCode = c.code
        LEFT JOIN contacts d ON a.contactCode = d.code
ORDER BY
    a.name;
```

Comment: Eu sugiro você realizar um subselect no ultimo left join trazendo os códigos juntamente com o max(endDate) para trazer o código mais recente, como você não colocou a estrutura dessa tabela não consigo montar o código para você :)

Comment: Irei atualizar a pergunta com a estrutura da tabela `negotiation`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o comando seguinte elucide o problema. Não utilizei o `Limit 1`. Usei o que é mais comum nesses casos, que é utilizar uma subconsulta para restringir o resultado conforme mencionado no comentário do [@heitor scalabrini](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/176220/heitor-scalabrini).

```
Select distinct
    a.*,
    b.name AS currentClubName,
    c.name AS transferorClubName,
    d.name AS contactName,
    d.phone AS contactPhone,
    d.phoneApp AS contactPhoneApp,
    d.email AS contactEmail,
    d.note AS contactNote,
    e.endDate
From athlete a
LEFT JOIN clubs b ON a.currentClubCode = b.code
LEFT JOIN clubs c ON a.transferorClubCode = c.code
LEFT JOIN contacts d ON a.contactCode = d.code
LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON a.code = e.athleteCode 
                       and e.endDate = (select max(endDate) 
                                          from negotiation e2
                                         where e2.athleteCode = a.code)
ORDER BY
    a.name;
```

### Algumas observações:

1. Incluí o `distinct` para suprimir possíveis duplicidades do resultado.
2. No trecho do SQL que você montou, consta `LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON e.athleteCode = a.code`.  Inverti para `LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON a.code = e.athleteCode` visto que no `Left Join` vai retornar os registros da relação mencionada na esquerda (*LEFT*).
3. Para fazer a junção *join* vamos restringir para selecionar apenas o registro de maior data `max(endDate)` para aquele determinado atleta conforme trecho:

> ```
> LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON a.code = e.athleteCode 
>                        and e.endDate = (select max(endDate) 
>                                           from negotiation e2
>                                          where e2.athleteCode = a.code)
> ```

### Distinct e DateTime:

Vale ressaltar que a necessidade de utilizar o `distinct` nesse caso se dá pelo motivo do campo `endDate` ser do tipo `date`, pois se fosse do tipo `datetime`, provavelmente não haveria duplicidade no resultado, principalmente se utilizasse o `datetime` com precisão de milissegundos.

Para saber mais sobre precisão do `datetime` no MySql pode consultar : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: Caramba que resposta sensacional. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Bom estou fazendo alguns testes com um banco de dados com 1000 atletas e percebi que o seu `select` tem uma média de `0,0189 segundos` enquanto da forma que fiz tem uma média de `0,0090 segundos`. Você tem ideia de onde pode estar esse gargalo?

Comment: Quanto mais `Left Join` utilizar, menor, em tese, será a performance da consulta. Pode testar retirar o `and e.endDate = (select max(endDate) 
  from negotiation e2
   where e2.athleteCode = a.code)` e colocar `where e.endDate = (select max(endDate) 
    from negotiation e2
   where e2.athleteCode = a.code)` desta forma, primeiro faz o join e depois a restrição da data. Outra opção seria criar uma função customizada para retornar o valor.

Answer (score -1):

Então é só ordenar os dados pelo endDate DESC e limitar o resultado em 1.

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.name AS currentClubName,
    c.name AS transferorClubName,
    d.name AS contactName,
    d.phone AS contactPhone,
    d.phoneApp AS contactPhoneApp,
    d.email AS contactEmail,
    d.note AS contactNote,
    e.endDate
FROM
    athlete a
        LEFT JOIN clubs b ON a.currentClubCode = b.code
        LEFT JOIN clubs c ON a.transferorClubCode = c.code
        LEFT JOIN contacts d ON a.contactCode = d.code
        LEFT JOIN negotiation e ON e.athleteCode = a.code
ORDER BY
    a.name, e.endDate desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Não, conforme expliquei preciso da listagem dos atletas, quero aplicar o `LIMIT 1`apenas na subi consulta da tabela `negotiation` para não ter duplicidade de atletas. O seu `select` só retorna 1 resultado geral, e não é isso que eu quero.