# Tranformar linhas específicas em colunas

Tags: mysql

tenho uma tabela de historicos de atividades e gostaria de transformar algumas linhas (de alguns status específicos) em colunas:

**Tabela Atual:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os status que desejo transformar em colunas são esses:

```
mod_analise_status_id = 10 (FORMALIZADO)

mod_analise_status_id = 9 OR mod_analise_status_id = 12 (CONFERIDO)
```

Ou seja, criar uma coluna **FORMALIZADO** e outra coluna **CONFERIDO** onde serão exibido o valor da coluna `datetime`. Ficaria dessa forma abaixo:

**Tabela desejada:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu exemplo a coluna CONFERIDO não retornou os valores certo. Meu codigo SQL é esse:

```
SELECT
h.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case 
    when (h.mod_analise_status_id = 10)   then h.datetime
    else h.datetime
end
as 'FORMALIZADO',
case 
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 AND h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
    else h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
FROM
    `negocios`.`mod_analise_historic` h
    INNER JOIN `negocios`.`mod_analise_historic` h2
    ON h.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id AND MONTH (h.datetime) = 06
WHERE
    MONTH (h.datetime) = 06
    AND YEAR (h.datetime) = 2021
```

**Tabela:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f4f3b

Comment: `(h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 AND h2.mod_analise_status_id =12)` isso nunca vai retornar, não é possível o valor ser **ao mesmo tempo** (`AND`) igual a 9 e 12 :)   deveria usar um `OR` ai

Comment: Sim, verdade. Foi um erro quando estava fazendo vários testes. Mas de fato o problema persiste mesmo ao corrigi-lo.

Comment: sem ter um exemplo com dados que se possa analisar fica difícil ajudar mais que isso. Tente montar um exemplo, pode ser no sqlfiddle ou db-fiddle para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você só quer como resultado os registros que já foram "Formalizado" e "Conferido", correto? Por exemplo, se uma solicitação foi Formalizada, mas não foi "Conferida", você não quer essa solicitação. Seria bom você criar o exemplo no sqlfiddle como o @RicardoPontual sugeriu.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Criei o exemplo com parte da minha database

Comment: @ClarckMaciel, exatamente. Preciso retornar as linhas que possuem ambos os status, como sendo cada um uma coluna, para que eu possa calcular o tempo gasto entre um e outro, e tentar exibir numa outra coluna.

Comment: No seu exemplo no Fiddle não apresenta o mod_analise_status_id igual 9, 10 ou 12. Pode editá-lo para parecer com a sua situação?

Comment: Teste: `SELECT
h.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h.mod_analise_status_id = 10)   then h.datetime
    else h.datetime
end
as 'FORMALIZADO',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
    else h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
FROM
    mod_analise_historic h
    INNER JOIN mod_analise_historic h2
    ON h.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
           and h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12
WHERE
  MONTH (h.datetime)= 06
  AND YEAR (h.datetime)= 2021
  AND H.mod_analise_status_id= 10`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [PIVOT - SELECT invertendo linha e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163386/pivot-select-invertendo-linha-e-coluna)

Comment: @ClarckMaciel, nesse sql não deu, ele repete o mesmo ID da solicitacao e as colunas CONFERIDO e FORMALIZADO não batem os meses e anos.

Comment: @Sorack é a mesma lógica que estou usando na minha consulta, porem o contexto de datetime e regra de negócio são diferentes, não consigo chegar no resultado desejado.

Comment: @gugoan, a repetição ocorre pelo motivo de ser uma tabela de histórico onde pode haver a repetição de um identificador. Você precisa incluir a lógica para informar qual o registro você deseja da segunda tabela. Então, acredito que você queira: `Solicitação; FORMALIZADO; CONFERIDO;`. Porém o `conferido` considera como verdade tanto o 9 como o 12, e como você está interessado na diferença de tempo, seria interessante a menor data  conferida para aquela solicitação(9 ou 12) naquele ano, correto?

Comment: com os dados que inseriu no exemplo não é possível simular o seu problema, eu mudei alguns status e as datas para fazerem match com a sua query, veja se é isso que quer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ce917/1   se não for, edite os dados para mostrar o problema. Na linha da solicitação "24" aparecem as duas datas, isso parece estar errado por causa do `join`, mas veja a query e confirme

Comment: @ClarckMaciel, sim, isso mesmo a repetição vai ocorrer, tem vários historicos para uma mesma solicitacao. Preciso exatamente de da solicitacao que tenha um historico de FORMALIZADO e tbm tenha um historico de CONFERIDO, daí consigo calcular o tempo entre eles e medir a produtividade.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, nessa consulta nao deu certo, testi aqui e alguns historicos de uma solicitacao por exemplo não vieram. Quase pensei que daria certo, seria so remover os nulos. Vou

Comment: foi o que imaginei, o problema é o join, qdo tiver um tempo dou uma olhada :)

Comment: @gugoan, criei uma estrutura simplificada para testar sua situação, verifique se entendi o que você precisa no endereço http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na situação em que se tem uma tabela de histórico, basicamente, teremos uma tabela com 3 campos: ID, DataHoraRegistro, Observação;
Esses campos responderão as perguntas: **Com qual registro aconteceu? Quando? O Quê? Quem?**.
**O campo `ID`:** relacionado a outra tabela, nesse exemplo, consideraremos o `solicitation_id` que deve estar relacionado a uma tabela de negócio, provavelmente, chamada `solicitation`.
**O campo `DataHoraRegistro`:** Informa quando um evento ocorreu, admitiremos o campo chamado `datetime` no seu exemplo.
**O campo `Observação, status_id, important_information`:** Conterá informações relevantes daquele registro.
Observe um exemplo de relacionamento entre tabelas que contém uma tabela de histórico:
[image: Tabela com histórico]

Exemplo disponível em: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table mod_analise_historic
(
    id bigint unsigned auto_increment,
    solicitation_id int null,
    datetime datetime null,
    mod_analise_status_id int null,
    constraint id
        unique (id)
);

insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (1, 25279, '2021-06-01 12:00:00', 10);
insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (2, 25246, '2021-06-01 06:46:59', 10);
insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (3, 24842, '2021-06-01 14:00:00', 10);
insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (4, 25246, '2021-06-01 08:47:46', 9);
insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (5, 25246, '2021-05-20 07:00:00', 1);
insert into mod_analise_historic (id, solicitation_id, datetime, mod_analise_status_id) values (6, 25246, '2021-06-01 08:30:00', 12);
```

**Consulta 1**:

```
Select * from mod_analise_historic
```

**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/0)**:

| id | solicitation_id | datetime | mod_analise_status_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25279 | 2021-06-01T12:00:00Z | 10 |
| 2 | 25246 | 2021-06-01T06:46:59Z | 10 |
| 3 | 24842 | 2021-06-01T14:00:00Z | 10 |
| 4 | 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:47:46Z | 9 |
| 5 | 25246 | 2021-05-20T07:00:00Z | 1 |
| 6 | 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:30:00Z | 12 |

**Consulta 2 - Exibindo 'Formalizado' e menor data para 'Conferido'**:

```
SELECT
h.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h.mod_analise_status_id = 10)   then h.datetime
end
as 'FORMALIZADO',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
FROM
    `mod_analise_historic` h
    INNER JOIN `mod_analise_historic` h2
            ON h.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
           and (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12)
           and h2.datetime = (Select min(datetime)
                                from mod_analise_historic h3
                               where h3.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
                                 and YEAR(h3.datetime) = YEAR(h2.datetime)
                                 and (h3.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h3.mod_analise_status_id =12)
               )
WHERE
    MONTH (h.datetime) = 06
    AND YEAR (h.datetime) = 2021
    AND H.mod_analise_status_id = 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/1)**:

| SOLICITATION | FORMALIZADO | CONFERIDO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T06:46:59Z | 2021-06-01T08:30:00Z |

**Consulta 3**:
Conjunto de registros que estão com situação 'FORMALIZADO'

```
SELECT h.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h.mod_analise_status_id = 10)   then h.datetime
end
as 'FORMALIZADO'
FROM
    `mod_analise_historic` h
WHERE
    MONTH(h.datetime) = 06
    AND YEAR (h.datetime) = 2021
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/2)**:

| SOLICITATION | FORMALIZADO |
| --- | --- |
| 25279 | 2021-06-01T12:00:00Z |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T06:46:59Z |
| 24842 | 2021-06-01T14:00:00Z |
| 25246 | (null) |
| 25246 | (null) |

**Consulta 4**:
'Conferido' com data `null` quando o status não significar 'Conferido'.

```
SELECT h2.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
from `mod_analise_historic` h2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/3)**:

| SOLICITATION | CONFERIDO |
| --- | --- |
| 25279 | (null) |
| 25246 | (null) |
| 24842 | (null) |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:47:46Z |
| 25246 | (null) |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:30:00Z |

**Consulta 5**:

Desta forma, obteve-se o conjunto de dados que estão na situação 'Conferido' e exibem a data da conferência.
Agora, como só nos interessa aqueles que estão conferidos, deve-se limitar na cláusula `where`, ficando assim:

```
SELECT h2.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
from `mod_analise_historic` h2
where (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12)
```

Observe que existem dois registros para um mesmo `solicitation_id`, e poderá haver vários outros no caso concreto.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/4)**:

| SOLICITATION | CONFERIDO |
| --- | --- |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:47:46Z |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:30:00Z |

**Consulta 6**:

Agora temos apenas aqueles que satisfazem a condição esperada para o segundo conjunto.
Mas podemos observar que, por trata-se de um histórico, situação comum em muitos banco de dados, poderá haver repetições, ou como na situação em questão, mais de um *status*  significando 'conferido', então agora **basta limitar o resultado com uma subconsulta que trará a menor data, ou maior data conforme o resultado esperado**.

Menor data usando função `MIN( )`:

```
  and h2.datetime = (Select MIN(datetime)
                                from mod_analise_historic h3
                               where h3.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
                                 and YEAR(h3.datetime) = YEAR(h2.datetime)
                                 and (h3.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h3.mod_analise_status_id =12)
                     )
```

Maior data usando função `MAX( )`:

```
  and h2.datetime = (Select MAX(datetime)
                                from mod_analise_historic h3
                               where h3.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
                                 and YEAR(h3.datetime) = YEAR(h2.datetime)
                                 and (h3.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h3.mod_analise_status_id =12)
                     )
```

**Menor** tempo decorrido para conferência:

```
SELECT h2.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
from `mod_analise_historic` h2
where (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12)
  and h2.datetime = (Select MIN(datetime)
                                from mod_analise_historic h3
                               where h3.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
                                 and YEAR(h3.datetime) = YEAR(h2.datetime)
                                 and (h3.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h3.mod_analise_status_id =12)
                     )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/5)**:

| SOLICITATION | CONFERIDO |
| --- | --- |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:30:00Z |

**Consulta 7**:

**Maior** tempo decorrido para conferência:

```
SELECT h2.solicitation_id as 'SOLICITATION',
case
    when (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12) then h2.datetime
end
as 'CONFERIDO'
from `mod_analise_historic` h2
where (h2.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h2.mod_analise_status_id =12)
  and h2.datetime = (Select MAX(datetime)
                                from mod_analise_historic h3
                               where h3.solicitation_id = h2.solicitation_id
                                 and YEAR(h3.datetime) = YEAR(h2.datetime)
                                 and (h3.mod_analise_status_id =9 or h3.mod_analise_status_id =12)
                     )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224d5b/9/6)**:

| SOLICITATION | CONFERIDO |
| --- | --- |
| 25246 | 2021-06-01T08:47:46Z |

Outro exemplo utilizando subconsulta com `min()` ou `max()`: [Subconsulta usando Max()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514300/limit-1-com-left-join/514376#514376)
Veja mais sobre [JOINs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441).

Comment: Você foi cirúrgico rsrs.. Meu cenário é exatamente esse, estava pensando em como tratar os casos em que há mais de um status CONFERIDO ou FORMALIZADO (geralmente por erro no fluxo ou erro do usuário), mas acabou me dando uma ótima solução ^^